# How to start description text after title by leaving same width for title

Tags: html, css

I have a title, and a description, the description always should start after title and continue next line by leaving the same width for title, it should look something like this img below [image]

Can any one help me with this please?

```
<div class="">
    <p><span>Description :</span> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. </span></p>
    <p>Disponibilité :  En stock </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That is essentially tabular data so nothing wrong with using a `<table>` to build it.

Comment: I dont know whats wrong with the people doing down vote? I mean I have enough information, I have attached img with it. still people are just doing down vote seems funny to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it with the HTML structure you provided.

Make it act like a table.

```
p {
  display: table; 
}
p span {
  display: table-cell;
}
p span:first-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/0az97ekw/

Or by using float with overflow.

```
p span:first-child {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
p span + span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/0az97ekw/1/

Comment: Thank you, this what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try to use tables:

```css
table td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td style="width: 100px;">Description :</td> <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. </td>
    </tr>
<tr><td style="width: 100px;">Disponibilité :</td><td>En stock </td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to use a grid system such as [Bootstrap's](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">Title Here</div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">Description Here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">Next Title Here</div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">Next Description Here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or manually style the widths, since your example is very simple, but still use the row-column structure.

Comment: Please check with bootstrap you can t achive the one you provided, please have a look on the img i attached

Comment: My example works. Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mObEXm Please don't downvote my answer because it does not immediately

Comment: Thank you @jaredsk